# Scorpion's Kunai Harpoon: a magical ability or an ordinary weapon?

Tags: weapon, mortal-kombat

Is Scorpion's *Kunai* harpoon is merely an ordinary weapon he carries or does he have the ability to generate and shoot as many *Kunai*s as he want from both of his hands?

As Hanzo Hasashi without special powers the *Kunai* is probably an ordinary weapon he carries. But in the animated films "Mortal Kombat Legends: Scorpion's Revenge" and the 2021 live action film it seemed that as a specter he can shoot as many *Kunai* harpoons as he wants and if they are damaged he can regenerate new ones. Moreover, in the "Mortal Kombat Legends: Scorpion's Revenge" he can even control the flight of the *Kunai*.

In the games it isn't that clear. Due to practical reasons, Scorpion indeed has an unlimited supply of *Kunai*s (if the opponent block the *Kunai* attack, the *Kunai* disappears and Scorpion can shoot a new one), however, in MK11 it is depicted as a weapon he carries and not generated from his palm.

Comment: There is extremely little continuity to *Mortal Kombat* (mostly for good reasons related to gameplay).  However, in MKII, it was revealed Scorpion was some kind of demonic or undead monstrosity, so having an infinite number of kunai seems perfectly reasonable.  After all, the games are full of magic, and Scorpion himself can also breathe fire.

Comment: In "The Journey Begins", the kunai is a purely physical weapon that he keeps tied to his wrist. Over time they become progressively less likely and more magical - https://mortalkombat.fandom.com/wiki/Kunai